# Firebase Firestore Security Rules: Can't compare the data sent from the user with the data on firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

First in my firestore I created a collection named "usr" that contains different  information of a user (below is an example):

```
{ 
 firstName: "John"
 lastName: "Doe"
 middleName: "Dimple"
 uniqueCode: "HsdaVBw"
}
```

and I use this documents to verify a user when logging in with this code:

```
Query query = data.collection("usr").
                            whereEqualTo("lastName", lastName).
                            whereEqualTo("firstName", firstName).
                            whereEqualTo("uniqueCode", uniqueCode);

verifyUser(query);

private void verifyUser(Query query) {

    query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                    login();
                }else{
                    Log.d("LoginPage ", "Login failed!");
                }
        }
    });
}
```

and after realizing that I chose test mode for my firestore, I created a rule that would also somehow validate the request data from the user.

```
 match /usr/{user} {
    allow read: if request.resource.data.lastName == resource.data.lastName && 
    request.resource.data.firstName == resource.data.firstName &&
    request.resource.data.uniqueCode == resource.data.uniqueCode;
}
```

so after I tried to login I got this error:

```
W/Firestore: (21.4.1) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(users where lastName == # com.google.firestore.v1.Value@a23137e8
integer_value: 0
string_value: "Doe" and firstName == # com.google.firestore.v1.Value@faaab68a
integer_value: 0
string_value: "John" and uniqueCode == # com.google.firestore.v1.Value@cb5c8a4b
integer_value: 0
string_value: "HsdaVBw" order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
```

is there something wrong in my rule? my code?

( I based my rule from this site: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query )

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here.  Why do you think the rule should allow that query?  What do you expect the query to return?  Please edit your question to be more clear.

Comment: Generally, you won't be submitting a document in the request if it's to read a document. What exactly are you trying to achieve?
Usually whether the user can read a document would be based on an aspect of the user (such as their UID), not a document they're submitting a request with.

Comment: so sorry for not fixing my question, uhm is that okay now?